# How to "select" a DB from a DBMS which should be queried by a GraphQL API?

Tags: graph, neo4j, next.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have a Neo4J DBMS with multiple DBs. And I want to query all of them with a GraphQL API in NextJS.

So is there a smart way to do this, like choosing which DB should be queried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a neat way of doing just that with the [@neo4j/graphql JS library](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/getting-started/).
Once you followed the getting started steps linked above, take a look at the [driver configuration page](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/3.0/driver-configuration/) of the documentation. Especially the part regarding [specifying which Neo4j database to use](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/driver-configuration/#_specifying_neo4j_database) may be of interest to you.